# for x = 0 to N in jQuery Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I've started to use jQuery Templates and I think it's great.
I am trying to build a pager.
My MVC action returns a JSON object with the current page and the total number of pages.
I would like to create a series of buttons. 
I've seen I can use `{{each}}` but it seems that I can only loop in collections.
Is there a way I can loop from **currentPage** to **totalPages** and build a series of buttons:

```
<script id="pagerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    <input type="radio" id="q_page_" name="radio" /><label for="q_page_">xxx</label>        
</script>
```

I know this code doesn't work but I would like to achieve something like this:

```
<script id="pagerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    {{each(currentPage, totalPages)}}
    <input type="radio" id="q_page_" name="radio" /><label for="q_page_">xxx</label>
    {{/each}}  
</script>
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: probably I need to rewrite it in a better way.

Comment: Probably. It's better now. But what are `x` and `y`?

Comment: @mkilmanas: Notice where it says "edited 2 mins ago"

Comment: Yes, I know it's a little bit confusing. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script id="pagerTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"> 
    {{each page }}
   <input type="radio" id="q_page_" name="radio" /><label for="q_page_">xxx</label>
    {{/each}}  
</script> 


<div id="pager"></div>

<script>

/* Render the template with the tmpl data */
$( "#pagerTmpl" ).tmpl( {page:new Array(10)} )
    .appendTo( "#pager" );



</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your solution might work. Thanks for that.